# Merging 2 pandas dataframes on a column that is non unique but has conditions on selecting the non-unique values (technically then unique)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Say I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'weight': [1,2,3,4], 'weight_units': ['lb','oz','oz', 'lb']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'weight': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'price':[1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3,3.1,3.2,3.3]})
```

The first dataframe (`df1`) contains the weight of an object along with the units of measurements of that weight `oz` & `lb` (ounces, pounds)

The second dataframe (`df2`) contains a column which has the weight value (in both pounds and ounces) and an associated price value. In the weight column after the value hits 16 (ounces) it restarts at 1 and goes up (1,2,3,4) signifying its now pounds.

*Note*: 1lb = 16oz

**My Question is:** How can I merge both of these dataframes on the weight column such that if the package has units of `oz` I start the merge using the first 16 values in `df2` and if its in `lb` I start the merge on the second dataframe from the 17th value onwards? Or any other sensible way of performing this merge correctly and getting the correct output if its in `lb` or `oz`

**Thoughts:**
My main concern was that since the weight column is not unique technically (since numbers 1-16 repeats for pounds and ounces) you cant simply just merge as if a package has a weight of 1 unless I can use the units condition it wouldnt know which price value to take.

**Ideal Output:**
A dataframe which has correctly merged taking the correct value if its `lb` or `oz` (pounds or ounces)

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'weight': [1,2,3,4], 'weight_units': ['lb','oz','oz', 'lb'], 'price':[2.7, 1.1,1.2,2]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is create new column, e.g. by:

```
df2['weight_units'] = ['oz'] * 16 + ['lb'] * (len(df2) - 16)
```

Or:

```
df2['weight_units'] = df2['weight'].eq(1).cumsum().map({1:'oz', 2:'lb'})
```

And then merge by `df1`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['weight','weight_units'])
```

Comment: Great thanks, Would you be able to explain your first line? Not entirely sure on how you can write `df2['weights_units']` like that.

Comment: @nishcs - It means `manually` way - in another words - first 16 values is `oz` and all another are `lb`

Comment: Ah ok thanks and in that sense the 2nd method is a `"automated"` way where it performs the mapping for you?